# Tengo un Permission Error Errno 13 en Python cuando quiero acceder a una ruta

Tags: python, base-de-datos, dataframe

Estoy haciendo un trabajo de visualizacion de datos con Pandas y tengo el dataframe en un archivo CSV. Primero importo la libreria de pandas y luego comienzo a armar el codigo para ingresar la ruta donde tengo el archivo, cuando ya tengo todo como debería me tira este error y no se que permiso tengo que otorgar para que me permita ver el head. Este es mi codigo, trabajo con el notebook Jupyter

```
df=pd.read_csv("C:/Capez 2.0/CLIENTE - Jimmy Willy/Jimmy Willy - Clientes")
df=head()
```

Comment: A riesgo de meter la pata, ¿no te falta la extensión?

Comment: Así, a ojo, tu cadena está mal escrita. Usa esta: 'r"C:\Capez 2.0\CLIENTE - Jimmy Willy\Jimmy Willy - Clientes" (Las barras van al revés)

Comment: Y por supuesto, ahí falta la extensión del archivo, como ya te apuntaron

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que comprobar que:

1. El usuario en el que estás abriendo el fichero tiene permisos en ese directorio.
2. No estás intentando guardar el archivo con el fichero abierto con otro programa (Excel p.e.)
3. Tanto la ruta como la extensión del archivo son correctas (este último no tiene extensión .csv)

Comment: Prueba a quitarle la extensión `.csv` en esta demo de `read_csv` `w3schools` y verás que sí es necesaria... [enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/Python/pandas/trypandas.asp?filename=demo_ref_df_size)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).